# Regular expression to match the registered trademark symbol

Tags: php, regex

I am using PHP `preg_replace()` to find and replace a company name with their logo. However, this also needs to include the registered trademark symbol (R) at them end. So, how can you write a regular expression to match the following?

`Company Name®` or `Company Name` or `Company Name<sup>®</sup>`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the Company Name always the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/Company Name(®|<sup>®<\/sup>|)/
```

or, to make it more clear:

```
/Company Name(®|<sup>®<\/sup>)?/
```

It would be even better if you'd chop out the html before, then use only

```
/Company Name®?/
```

Comment: Are groups implied to be 0 or more matches? or do you still need a `*` after you last paren?

Comment: No, but the last expression in the or-group is the empty string :-) Already edited to explain.

Comment: Gotcha, it just seemed like the first regex couldn't match `Company Name`, only `Company Name®` or `Company Name<sup>®</sup>`